# Has the target of a HTTP CONNECT tunnel to be reachable from both client and proxy?

Tags: ssh, apache-httpd, http, http-proxy

I am trying to tunnel ssh via HTTP. My apache virtual host config looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName proxy.example.org
    ProxyRequests On
    AllowCONNECT 22

    <Proxy *>
        Require all denied
    </Proxy>
    <Proxy ssh-container>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Proxytunnel outputs the following:

```
proxytunnel -E -p proxy.example.org:443 -d ssh-container:22                                                                                                       
->
Via proxy.example.org:443 -> ssh-container:22
HTTP return code: 404 Not Found
```

`ssh-container` is a docker container in the same network of the apache httpd container. `ssh ssh-container` is successful from inside the apache container.

If I now change `ssh-container` to something which is reachable from the client requesting the tunnel via proxy.example.org to the sshd (e.g. ssh.example.org:22) it works.

So why is that? I am assuming that if I tunnel via HTTP CONNECT that only the proxy has to be able to reach the target. I suspected some DNS issues (e.g. client has to resolve DNS), but even connecting via the proxy with the container IP as the target does not work.